# How to select (and copy) all posts within a conversation in the macOS Messages app?

Tags: macos, messages

The following question [Copy all messages of a conversation in one folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93863/how-to-copy-all-messages-of-a-conversation-in-one-folder) mentions `View | Select all` but I do not see that option.

[image]

I have a conversation with a couple hundred entries: i really can not go and right click on each one. How can I bulk copy these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Messages on Mac, select the conversation you need. Click File > Print > In the drop down menu, select 'Save as PDF'.

Comment: Excellent!  It is surprising that "Export -> PDF" only saves the currently visible screen whereas Print | Save as PDF saves everything.  I'll ask another question separately: does Messages "forget" conversations older than 90 days .. seems hanging on that